# Formatting text (from array) on prompt window

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a very simple prompt that outputs elements from an array:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

function alertMessage() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(`List of numbers: ${arr}`);
}

alertMessage();
```

The message currently reads like this:

List of numbers: 1,2,3,4,5,6

However, I would like it to create a new line after each element (with no commas), so it would look like the below example. What would be the best way to do this?

List of numbers:

1

2

3

4

5

6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that in your script, `arr` is an array. So, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(`List of numbers: ${arr}`);
```

#### To:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(`List of numbers: \n${arr.join("\n")}`);
```

- If you want the double line breaks, please modify to `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(`List of numbers: \n${arr.join("\n\n")}`);`

#### Reference:

- [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)